# MPEG Dash streaming on multiple screen using EXOplayer

Tags: streaming, mpeg-dash, exoplayer

I have a requirement to play the MPEG Dash stream on multiple screen. So I want to play **same stream** on different devices using EXO player.

If anyone have any idea, how to play same MPEG DASH stream on multiple screen please get back to me.

Thank You,

Comment: Stack overflow isn't her to ask people to write code for you. You must have researched your problem and tried some code for yourself first. Then you post a queston with your problem, the code you've tried so far, the expected behavour and the behaviour that you're getting - See Here .. [ask] .. and [mcve].. Cheers

Comment: I know what should I ask on stack overflow. I asked this questions only because I am new to MPEG Dash streaming and I need right direction to look into for this requirement.

Comment: We'd need more details on how the screens are connected - is this a dual-screen device, device+gear, Android TV or are you using Chromecast? This will influence the solution drastically.

Having said that, a starting point would be to look at how ExoPlayer takes a Surface for the Video Renderer. Attach a SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener instance to the surface, then use Surface's copyFrom() to render to your secondary surfaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to MPEG-DASH I suggest to read some introducing articles, like http://www.streamingmedia.com/Articles/Editorial/What-Is-.../What-is-MPEG-DASH-79041.aspx, and https://www.bitcodin.com/blog/2015/04/mpeg-dash/.

Next step could be to define which platforms will be supported and if you are going for a native App, like [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer), browser based playout, like [dash.js](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/wiki), or [bitmovin](https://www.bitmovin.com/), or make use of the native MPEG-DASH support of some devices, like some [Smart TVs](https://www.hbbtv.org/).

Once you share that knowledge and what is the goal of your efforts, people on this platform can help you with more details.

Comment: Thank you Alexander Wolf, it's a really good article to read for MPEG Dash.